# How do you get promoted to Masters in League Play

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I was wondering how you get promoted to Masters in Black Ops 2. I've been playing a lot of league play where I get on a win streak of a few games then lose. I am in Platinum currently, but can't seem to get bumped up even though I beat a lot of masters ranked people and play with them regularly, often times I'm one of two people that are platinum and the rest are Masters. Does anyone know what it will take to get bumped up to masters? I'm just trying to figure out the system so that I can get into masters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Basically, you have to be one of the best.**

According to [the rules](http://community.callofduty.com/community/call_of_duty/english/black_ops_2/blog/2012/12/01/league-play-overview--call-of-duty-world-league), it's all about winning, plain and simple.

> Divisions
>
> There are six divisions that reflect the approximate skill distribution of the active population in a Series.
>
> Masters: **top 2% of the active population.**
>   Platinum: next 18%.
>   Gold: next 20%.
>   Silver: next 20%.
>   Bronze: next 20%.
>   Bronze: bottom 20%.
>
> You will start in a Division based on your hidden skill rating determined by placement matches. As you play, ***if you win enough you may be promoted to a higher Division***.

Answer (score 2):

It is not as much based on wins as it is your individual skill. I lost 3/5 placement matches and came in Platinum because I was pulling 7-8k points in hardpoint and such. They go by your score and objective mainly for placement. Winning will bump you up in the ladder, but leading your team to victory is your path to Masters.
However, if you win many placement matches against lower ranked players such as silver and below, you will be ranked lower, if you lose against platinums and masters, you won't be ranked down that much as they are experienced players who prove a challenge to anybody.

Comment: Yeah I got bumped to masters after not playing for a day or 2. I got on and was randomly in masters league. I'll take it for sure. I think being on top of your team and or lobby is crucial to getting bumped up :)

Answer (score 0):

My friends and I lost 4 matches in the placement and got platinum. Then later after a while my friends got into masters by winning 1-2 matches. So my best advice is waiting a few days to a week before playing league.

Comment: Were your friends previously in Masters? Because I was in Masters last season and lost 2 of my placements and tied another winning the other 2. I got placed in Platinum won the next game and bumped up to Masters.